# I am trying to make a simple quiz in python but everything returns False?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Every answer I put in returns False; even A. Can someone please help me.

```
def space():
print' '
print 'Welcome to the quiz'
space()
print 'Chose the correct answer'
space()
print 'Who am I? '
space()
print "A. Zachary  "
print "B. Max"
print "C. Nick"
print "D. All of the above"
print 'type in the correct answer'
answer = raw_input()
if answer == 'a':
    print True
else:
    print False
```

Comment: first of all, the second line of your code should be indented, or else its not considered a part of the function

Comment: `'A'` and `'a'` are not equal. What happens when you enter a lower-case `a`?

Comment: also, its case sensitive, so `'a' == 'A'` will return False

Comment: 'A' and 'a' are different characters. Could this be the problem? Also try printing out the answer string, and see if it really is just 'a' or if you also have a space or a carriage return in there.

Comment: `if answer == 'a':` => `if answer.lower() == 'a':`

Answer (score 1):

Change `if answer == 'a':` to `if answer == 'a' or answer == 'A':` OR, as per [the suggestion of Paul Rooney](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41133831/7204790), you can use `if answer.lower() == 'a':`.

Also, in `def space():`, `print ' '` should be indented.

```
def space():
    print ' '
print 'Welcome to the quiz!'
space()
print 'Chose the correct answer.'
space()
print 'Who am I? '
space()
print "A. Zachary  "
print "B. Max"
print "C. Nick"
print "D. All of the above"
print 'Type in the correct answer.'
answer = raw_input()
if answer == 'a' or answer == 'A':
    print True
else:
    print False
```

Typing `A` or `a` yields `True`.

[python](/questions/tagged/python)

Comment: regardless of value of `answer` `if answer == 'a' or 'A':` will always result in `True`, because `A` is a boolean statement on its own and its `True`. So `anything || True` is `True`. It should be `if answer == 'a' or answer == 'A'`. Its actually more concise to write `if answer in ('a', 'A')`, `if answer.lower() == 'a':` is better as it avoids repetition.

Comment: Also, `if answer in ('a', 'A')` are `answer == 'a' or 'A'` both concise IMHO. I just don't understand the downvote, though

Comment: `if answer in ('a', 'A')` and `answer == 'a' or 'A'` are both concise IMHO*, apologies for the error

Comment: BUT, I agree with you on this: `if answer.lower() == 'a': is better as it avoids repetition

Comment: `if answer.lower() == 'a'` IS MUCH BETTER THAN those two :-)

Comment: because its wrong. Try it with another value where you expect the result to be `False` it will **alway** return `True`.

Comment: Ok, post edited for correctness. "Try it with another value where you expect the result to be False", it WILL NOW return `False`.